# laravel paginate a query that has a limit clause

Tags: laravel, eloquent

You have a database of 10,000 customers.  You want to limit your search to only 500 of those customers but want to paginate the results by 50 results each page.  So the last page, page 10, of the results would have 50 results.  There would be no page 11.

Is this possible with eloquent/laravel?  Something like "select * from people order by field desc limit 500" and then perform pagination on those results?

Paginate seems to use ->take() and ->offset(), which ignore ->limit().  I'd like to be able to use all three.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/pagination

Comment: maybe you could do the 500 limit as a subquery and then paginate the main query?

Answer (score 3):

With a subquery

```
        $events = DB::table(function ($query) {
            $query->selectRaw('*')
                ->from('system_events_collected')
                ->orderBy('event_at','desc')
                ->take(500);
        })->paginate(10);
```

in this case, the data I want to paginate is in a table called system_events_collected.  A subquery gets the first 500 rows from this table, then pagination is performed on the results.

Answer (score 1):

Try the LengthAwarePaginator, link to similar issue: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-use-lengthawarepaginator-manual-paginator

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
Article::where([['user_id','=',auth()->user()->id]])
            ->where([['title','LIKE',"%".$text_val."%"]])
            ->orderBy('id','DESC')
            ->get();
```

Or use "DB"

Comment: Is this for the same question?

Comment: Then it's pointless since the question is about pagination, not general queries

Comment: @Snapey

the question was
"is this possible with eloquent/laravel? Something like "select * from people order by field desc limit 500" and then perform pagination on those results?"
so ive give an example about that and instead of get you can put paginate ! 
its actually simple
and add limit by adding take(nbr)